# I attempted to install a custom ROM, and my device crashed in both fastboot and recovery modes. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, crash, recovery, fastboot

I attempted to install a custom ROM, and my device crashed in both fastboot and recovery modes. How can I fix this? Please If you know the solution...

I want to recover my phone, I have tried to open recovery and fastboot mode it shows logo and shutdown after some time or instantly.